# Grease pencil and lattice modifier

Tags: modifiers, grease-pencil, lattice

Good day everyone. I’m very new to grease pencil and I’ve been closely following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXLs5lVX0ys&t=1140s by Sketchy Squirrel.

Here’s the problem, the moment I try use the lattice modifier it immediately deforms the grease pencil stroke. I played around with the object origins, but that didn’t help much.

[image]

Comment: check this: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/lattice.html#usage  Basically it might because you should get the lattice in the right place and at the right size in object mode, not in edit mode as that will deform the result

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you apply the scale of the object or modify the lattice in *Edit Mode*.

The lattice object should be positioned and scaled in *Object Mode*, and the scale should not be applied.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)